# createStackNavigator with Expo and Typescript, doesn't render anything

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, expo

### UPDATE:

[Git Repo of NotWorkingProject](https://github.com/dhavaljardosh/notWorkingExpo)

---

Trying to use

`react-navigation` package in React Native(Expo-**Typescript**)

the same way as we do with regular React Native (Expo - Vanilla JS)

But it doesn't render anything on the screen.

---

**AppNavigator.tsx**

```
import {createAppContainer, createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import * as React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Text} from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: '#f0f',
        flex: 1
    }
});

const HomeScreen = () => (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <View>
            <Text>PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE RENDER THIS</Text>
        </View>
    </View>
);

HomeScreen.navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Home'
};

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({Home: HomeScreen});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

**App.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ViewStyle } from 'react-native';
import AppContainer from './navigation/AppNavigator'

const styles = {
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  } as ViewStyle
};


const App = (style:Object): {} => {
  const { container } = styles;
  return (
    <View style={container}>
      <AppContainer/>
    </View>
  );
}

export default  App;
```

INCASE IF NEEDED:

**package.json**

```
{
  dependencies: {
    expo: "^34.0.1",
    react: "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-34.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.4",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.1"
  },
  devDependencies: {
    "@types/react": "^16.8.23",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.57.65",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^6.0.0",
    typescript: "^3.4.5"
  }
}
```

Please let me know what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to put the device aside.

**App.tsx**   **[Example](https://snack.expo.io/@taeeh/stack-navigator-typescript-example)** I created

```
import {createAppContainer, createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import * as React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Text} from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: '#f0f',
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent:"center",
        alignItems:"center"
    }
});

const HomeScreen = () => (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <View>
            <Text>PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE RENDER THIS</Text>
        </View>
    </View>
);

HomeScreen.navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Home'
};

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({Home: HomeScreen});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Comment: did you render it into the component App.js ?

Comment: It says that a container is needed.

Comment: @DhavalJardosh  I'm sorry. I was testing with Expo's SDK32. I added an app container.

Comment: @DhavalJardosh updated my answer. However, you do not need to separate the container files.

Comment: It's still not working, I created a git repo so you can take a look.
https://github.com/dhavaljardosh/notWorkingExpo

Comment: You wrote my answer in 'AppNavigator.tsx'. When you remove the 'AppNavigator.tsx' file and write its contents in 'App.tsx', the problem disappears.

Comment: in `App.tsx`, just removing the `<View>` wrapper around `<AppContainer/>`, it's working.
Will need to investigate what's wrong. This was so silly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the AppContainer

```
import AppNavigator from "./config/router";



    import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ViewStyle } from 'react-native';
import AppContainer from './navigation/AppNavigator'

const styles = {
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  } as ViewStyle
};


const App = (style:Object): {} => {
  const { container } = styles;
  return (

      <AppContainer/>

  );
}
export default  App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, `View` component blocking the view of the app container and your components. try to use this way, it worked for me:

```
    ....
    ....
    const HomeScrconst HomeScreen = () => (
        <>
          <Text>PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE RENDER THIS</Text>
        </>
    );

    HomeScreen.navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Home'
    };

    const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({Home: HomeScreen});

    export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);een = () => (
        <>
          <Text>PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE RENDER THIS</Text>
        </>
    );

    HomeScreen.navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Home'
    };

    const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({Home: HomeScreen});

    export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```